# Ionic - Google places and Autocomplete location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have work on the project on Ionic 2 and I have implemented the map so far, but I can not get out of that point. I needed to be shown the way I should go in order to add Google Place and Autocomplete to the project.

What can I do?

HTML:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Search</ion-label>
    <ion-input id="places" type="text" name="search"></ion-input>       
</ion-row>
<div #map id="map"></div>
```

HOME.ts

```
export class HomePage {

public latitude: number;
public longitude: number;

@ViewChild('map') mapElement;
map: any;
marker: any;
search: string;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {
 /*platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.InitMap();
 });*/
}
 ionViewDidLoad(){
 this.InitMap();
}

InitMap() {

  this.setLocation();
  let input = document.getElementById('places');
  let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {

    let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
    this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
    alert(this.latitude + ", " + this.longitude);
    console.log(place);
  });

}

setLocation() {

  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.550513, 9.994241);
  let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);    
  this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: this.map,
   });
  }

 }
```

What is wrong?
Thank's

Comment: what exactly are you trying and what is the response?

Comment: As I said. I would like to implement an autocomplete to the map.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Simply does not work. And returns nothing. I can not see what's wrong.

Comment: Let me know if it works

Comment: @Michael help me in understanding your question.. you want to get autocomplete while typing in textbox or you want to show directions to the place?

Comment: @varun aaruru, Both!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> SOLVED! After a long time I was able to find a solution to my problem. Here's the solution:

Home.html:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input (click)="showAddressModal()" [(ngModel)]="address.place"type="text" placeholder="Pick an address">              </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Home.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, ModalController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {AutocompletePage} from './autocomplete';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  address;

  constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private ModalCtrl:ModalController
  ) {
    this.address = {
      place: ''
    };
  }

  showAddressModal () {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(AutocompletePage);
    let me = this;
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
      this.address.place = data;
    });
    modal.present();
  }
}
```

AutocompletePage.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Enter address</ion-title>
    <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="autocomplete.query" [showCancelButton]="true"   (ionInput)="updateSearch()" (ionCancel)="dismiss()"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of autocompleteItems" tappable   (click)="chooseItem(item)">
      {{ item }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

AutocompletePage.ts:

```
import {Component, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import {ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/autocomplete.html'
})

export class AutocompletePage {
  autocompleteItems;
  autocomplete;

  latitude: number = 0;
  longitude: number = 0;
  geo: any

  service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

  constructor (public viewCtrl: ViewController, private zone: NgZone) {
    this.autocompleteItems = [];
    this.autocomplete = {
      query: ''
    };
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }

  chooseItem(item: any) {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(item);
    this.geo = item;
    this.geoCode(this.geo);//convert Address to lat and long
  }

  updateSearch() {

    if (this.autocomplete.query == '') {
     this.autocompleteItems = [];
     return;
    }

    let me = this;
    this.service.getPlacePredictions({
    input: this.autocomplete.query,
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'de'
    }
   }, (predictions, status) => {
     me.autocompleteItems = [];

   me.zone.run(() => {
     if (predictions != null) {
        predictions.forEach((prediction) => {
          me.autocompleteItems.push(prediction.description);
        });
       }
     });
   });
  }

  //convert Address string to lat and long
  geoCode(address:any) {
    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, (results, status) => {
    this.latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    this.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    alert("lat: " + this.latitude + ", long: " + this.longitude);
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: yah, this is perfect to use but its not giving latitude and longitude, so can u please guide me to have latlang.

Comment: Hallo  Atam_Jeet Singh, You see the last update. To get Lat and Long, you need to convert the address with Geocode.

Comment: Hi Michael, for me this solution is not working, first I had to add `declare let google: any;` But I still have this error when I try to open autocomplete modal page `TypeError: Cannot read property 'AutocompleteService' of undefined` Did you also have this error?

Comment: Hi Kicker, In AutocompletePage.ts, after imports, add: declare var google: any;

Comment: Great! do we really need a new AutoCompletePage can google autocompeteservice integrated directly to the input box where user enters

Comment: @Kicker Fixes for `TypeError: Cannot read property 'AutocompleteService' of undefined` make sure you include **`libraries=places`** in your Google JS declaration, ie: `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=xxx"></script>`

Comment: I have tried , it is working fine but only once when i initialize app. i need to find google places autocomplete every time

Comment: I have been using this for a while and its been working perfectly. However it stopped working when i build for Android 28. Anyone else had that issue? Any solutions?

Answer (score 6):

Use elementref for accessing the ion input used instead of `document.getElementById`
Try:

```
<ion-input #places type="text" name="search"></ion-input>
```

In your component class,

```
 import {Elementref } from '@angular/core'; 
 @ViewChild("places")
  public places: ElementRef;
    InitMap(){
    this.setLocation();
    let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.places.nativeElement);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {

        let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
        this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
        alert(this.latitude + ", " + this.longitude);
        console.log(place);
      });

    }
```

Check angular docs [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately it does nothing.
In the Console I have an Error:  `InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement`

Comment: Oh.. Alright I will change my  answer.. I thought it took value

Comment: Great Suraj,
Many bugs with `let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete (this.places.nativeElement);`. To show the map I need to have  `@ViewChild ('map') mapElement`

Comment: As I said,   I need to have  `@ViewChild ('map') mapElement` to show my map. If I add `@ViewChild("places")`, Dont show nothing.  This is Error: `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: google is not defined`

Comment: That is a different  error.  Have you declared google  globally?

Comment: https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/ have you added the script?

Comment: Yes, I have followed all his tutorials. But there is no on autocomplete.

Comment: Here google api: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myApi&libraries=places"async defer></script>`

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-google-maps-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined/22550/18

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is "google places object", then your code can be very simple like so:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Search your city</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="placeAutofill" id="googlePlaces" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

And in my code:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
   // Google Places API auto complete
   let input = document.getElementById('googlePlaces').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
   let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {types: ['geocode']});
   google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
     // retrieve the place object for your use
     let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
   });
}
```

Comment: I have used this solution, it is working fine but only once when i initialize app. i need to find google places autocomplete everytime