# Autocomplete Google Places api Modal with Ionic - "Cannot find name 'google'."

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have an ionic project in which I am trying to get the error message `"Cannot find name 'google'."` to go away. I have tried putting the google maps api script in the head as well as the foot of the page, installing the [ionic native google maps package](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/), `typings install dt~google.maps --global`...What is strange is that the modal is functioning (see picture), but I first need to close an error window. One idea that I have is that I tried to run `npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev` but I got the error messages:

```
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.2.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.2.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.2.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.2.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/core@2.2.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.2.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.5 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
```

[image]

I first have to close an error window like the following in order to see that modal, so Google must be loading.

[image]

The code that I got is from the following tutorial, where a few other people seem to have had similar issues: http://devfanaticblog.com/google-maps-autocomplete-for-ionic-2-applications/

**index.html**
I've included this in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_api_key&amp;libraries=places"></script>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { NavController, ModalController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AutocompletePage} from './autocomplete';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  public address;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    this.address = {
      place: ''
    };
  }

  showAddressModal () {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(AutocompletePage);
    let me = this;
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
      this.address.place = data;
    });
    modal.present();
  }

}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Location</ion-label>
      <ion-input (click)="showAddressModal()" [(ngModel)]="address.place" type="text" placeholder="Enter Pickup Address"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**autocomplete.ts**

```
import {Component, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import {ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { GoogleMaps, GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, LatLng, CameraPosition, MarkerOptions, Marker } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';


@Component({
  templateUrl: './autocomplete.html'
})

export class AutocompletePage {
  public autocompleteItems;
  public autocomplete;
  public service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

  constructor (public viewCtrl: ViewController, private zone: NgZone) {
    this.autocompleteItems = [];
    this.autocomplete = {
      query: ''
    };
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }

  chooseItem(item: any) {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(item);
  }

  updateSearch() {
    if (this.autocomplete.query == '') {
      this.autocompleteItems = [];
      return;
    }
    let me = this;
    this.service.getPlacePredictions({ input: this.autocomplete.query, componentRestrictions: {country: 'US'} }, function (predictions, status) {
      me.autocompleteItems = []; 
      me.zone.run(function () {
        predictions.forEach(function (prediction) {
          me.autocompleteItems.push(prediction.description);
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**autocomplete.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Enter address</ion-title>
    <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="autocomplete.query" [showCancelButton]="true" (ionInput)="updateSearch()" (ionCancel)="dismiss()"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of autocompleteItems" autofocus tappable (click)="chooseItem(item)">
      {{ item }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Other relevant links that I've reviewed:

- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-typescript-error-cannot-find-name-google-discussion/49990
- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-places-autocomplete-on-an-ion-input-component-in-ionic-2/52890
- [Ionic 2 - Google places and Autocomplete location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427915/ionic-2-google-places-and-autocomplete-location)
- https://ionicallyspeaking.com/2016/06/07/google-places-autocomplete-and-ionic-2/
- https://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-google-maps-with-an-ionic-application/
- https://github.com/guillefd/ionic2-google-maps-autocomplete/
- [How to install Typescript typings for google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064697/how-to-install-typescript-typings-for-google-maps)
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/
- https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up quite simple:

In `declarations.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'googlemaps';
```